# In r ggplot, is it possible to adjust the spacing between boxplots on the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say you want a simple boxplot, without any subgroups:

```
some_data %>%
        ggplot(aes(x=factor_1,
                   y=some_outcome)) + 
        geom_boxplot(width=0.2,notch = TRUE)
```

[image: an example image of two boxplots]

How do you adjust the space between the two boxes, **without changing the box width**? So I just want to move the boxes closer or further away.

No online resourse seems to tackle this specific question. They either show how to change the box width, or they discuss the grouped boxplots that use the `fill` argument and how to adjust the spacing between the grouped boxes using `position_dodge`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does that https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that you are drawing a plot into a plotting window with a fixed width. If you want the boxes to be closer together but remain the same size, and you don't want to change the size of the plotting window, then *something* needs to take up the extra space you have created. This can be achieved either by expanding the x-axis range of the plotting panel itself, or the margins *around* the plotting panel.

Let's start with a concrete example of data so we can run your code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

some_data <- data.frame(factor_1 = c("0", "1"),
                        some_outcome = rnorm(200))
```

Now we can use your plotting code to get a reasonable replica of your plot:

```r
some_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor_1,
             y=some_outcome)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.2, notch = TRUE)
```

[image]

Now, we can move the boxes closer together by expanding the x-axis range like this:

```r
some_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor_1,
             y=some_outcome)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.67, notch = TRUE) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(2, 2))
```

[image]

You can see that the extra space is taken up with some additional room in the panel on either side of the boxes.

An alternative is to make the panel narrower by increasing the margins around it, thereby allowing whitespace to take up the extra room:

```r
some_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor_1,
             y=some_outcome)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, notch = TRUE) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(10, 150, 10, 150))
```

[image]

I think the second option looks nicer. However, you would get a similar look if you just make your plotting window the correct size, then use your original plotting code (with appropriately selected `width` parameter)

```r
# Drag plotting window to correct size, then run:

some_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor_1,
             y=some_outcome)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.4, notch = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to set the figure width with code, instead of adjusting the window size manually? I'm asking because I'm using an .Rmd file, where multiple figures are being plotted within the same code chunk. I know I can set a chunk parameter fig.width but that would apply to all the figures I'm printing in that code chunk, while I might want to have different widths for different figures. Any way to do it without printing every figure in a separate code chunk?

Comment: @user16094080 yes, the second example I gave does that. You simply increase the margins around the plot.